# How detect which class trying to generate instance of current class

Tags: c#, .net

I don't know how to implement follow logic.

Let say we have class form1 and class form2. Also, we have class Panel and we want in Panel class to implement follow logic:

```
if form1 is calling Panel
{
   Panel.Size = Size1;
}  
else if form2 is calling Panel
{
   Panel.Size = Size2;
}
```

Thank you in advance for help...

Comment: While this is possible, it's hacky and I'm not convinced that it's the right thing to do. What is the reason that you want to do this? There may be a much better solution.

Comment: Why not set the size where you create the panel? or pass the size as parameter?

Comment: you can try and hack it using `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace`

Comment: The title says 'generate' while in the code you kept 'calling'. Are you creating a new instance of Panel or calling a method in Panel?

Comment: @Matthew Watson - i solved this task on the other way (with overriding) and that is better way, but i realized during solving this task that it would be useful in some situations to solve this kind of problem in way that i described above. I tried to realize mentioned problem by using Stack Trace and Stack Frame but i found that it is not reliable. I thought that maybe there is a better and more reliable way of detecting caller class....

Comment: @aSharma i want to create a new instance of Panel...

Comment: Then I'd suggest to pass the size in the constructor of Panel. So that you can pass the size from the caller. Panel should not depend on' who is calling it' , rather the caller must specify what size of the Panel it needs.

Answer (score 1):

This will print you Type of calling class, you might need to conigure frame numbers, but this gives you basic idea:

```
public static void PrintCallerClassType()
{
    var stackTrace = new StackTrace(new StackFrame(1));
    var frame = stackTrace.GetFrame(0);
    Console.WriteLine(frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType);
}
```

Comment: This isn't reliable. JIT could inline the method if it thinks inlining would help. In that case, this code will fail. I recommend any readers to stay away from this; It you're debugging, this is fine, otherwise please refrain using this.